# How to merge a serialized protobuf with a another protobuf without deserializing the first

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to take a serialized protobuf that makes up part of another protobuf and merge them together without having to deserialize the first protobuf.

For example, given a protobuf wrapper:

```
syntax = "proto2";

import "content.proto";

message WrapperContent {

 required string metatData = 1;
 required Content content = 2;

}
```

And then imagine we get a serialized version of ***Content*** below (i.e. ***Content*** is coming that is coming from a remote client):

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Content {

 required string name = 1;
 required bytes payload = 2;

}
```

Do you know if any way I can inject the serialized ***Content*** into the ***WrapperContent*** without first having to deserialize ***Content***.

The reason I'm trying to inject ***Content*** without deserializing it, is that I'm try and save on the overhead of deserializing the message.

If that answer is, no, it's not possible. That is still helpful.

Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In protobuf, submessages are stored like `bytes` fields.

So you can make a modified copy of your wrapper:

```
message WrapperContentBytes {
 required string metatData = 1;
 required bytes content = 2;
}
```

and write the already serialized content data into the `content` field.

Decoders can use the unmodified `WrapperContent` message to decode also the submessage. The binary data on the wire will be the same so decoders do not know the difference.